# Botpress behind a Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, botpress

I am thinking of setting up multiple chatbots as in a containerized platform lets say docker or Kubernetes, and I would want to be able to access these chatbots through a reverse proxy such as Nginx. any help is appreciated.

My example scenario

I have a multiple chatbots, lets call them  **Bravo, Charlie, Delta**

- Bravo's IP address and port is 10.0.0.2:8080
- Charlie's IP : 10.0.0.3:8080
- Delta's IP :10.0.0.4:8080

All of these bots are living in containers behind a nginx proxy. 
Now if I want to access these chatbots, I am able to get to the browser with 10.0.0.2:8080  and use the chatbots,

If I could setup a domain  **(alpha,org)** and want to access these chatbots as alpha,com/bravo , or alpha,com/charlie and alpha,com/delta  how would I be able to achieve this.?

The Proxy pass directive works only for the index_html and the chatbot application seems to have some kind of base url path that I am unable to figure out.
nginx returns a blank page if I inspect the traffic. Help me debug this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nginx-ingress controller with this ingress definition: (But first you need to deploy nginx-ingress controller on your cluster, you can use this [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/))

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alpha-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: alpha.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /bravo
        backend:
          serviceName: BravoService
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /charlie
        backend:
          serviceName: CharlieService
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /delta
        backend:
          serviceName: DeltaService
          servicePort: 80 # You could also use named ports if you already named the port in the service like bravo-http-port
```

This expects that you have already defined and deployed your services with associated deployments. for Ex:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: BravoService
  labels:
    app: bravo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: bravo
  ports:
    - name: bravo-http-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: bravo-port
      nodePort: 8080

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bravo-deployment
  labels:
    app: bravo
spec:
  # init with 3 replicas
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bravo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bravo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bravo-container
        image: my-docker-repo/project:1.0
        ports:
        - name: bravo-port
          containerPort: 8080
```

If you have more questions on this please don't hesitate.

Comment: Thanks for the response @alireza-david , I have tried this path based routing as you have mentioned. But when I do this, I am unable to get the contents for the webpage. like the css files, the JS scripts for the frontend is not loading. I get a 404 in the url path http://alpha.com/bravo/css  . It would be great if you could help in stripping the URI to forward the requests to the containers as how it gets to 
http://10.0.0.2:8080/css

Comment: Oh, I had to mentioned that you can use this rewrite annotaion. I've updated the answer aswell. 

  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /